# Get master key to access HttpTrigger in Azure Function 2x

Tags: azure-functions, azure-triggers

I need to get a key to access code for HttpTrigger `https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/api/registration?code=Key`. In Azure function 1x, with Url `https://$functionAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions/admin/masterkey`
will return my master key like `{"masterKey":"ehp9f***************************"}` but, in Azure Function 2x this way isn't work. How can I  connect HttpTrigger in PowerShell with Azure Function 2x. Another SCM Api or syntax instead of `(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://mydomain.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions/admin/masterkey -Headers @{"Authorization"=$accessToken;"If-Match"="*"} ).Masterkey` in Azure function 1x.

Thanks for your support

Comment: I wonder how to get too :((

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue check this wiki doc:[ARM Impact](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Changes-to-Key-Management-in-Functions-V2#arm-impact) and this issue:[listSecrets broken for function keys in V2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3411).

For now there is a new api however it's not released you could check this issue:[Expand/Improve Functions ARM APIs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3994).

Here is a sample api:

`POST api/sites/{name}[/slots/{slot}]/host/default/listkeys`

```
{
"masterKey": "<keyvalue>",
"functionKeys": {
  "default": "<keyvalue>",
  "my-key": "<keyvalue>"
},
"systemKeys": {
  "test-system": "<keyvalue>",
  "my-key": "<keyvalue>"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who cannot find the `_master` key as described in this article [Get the function's master key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http#get-the-functions-master-key), go the the root of the function resource and look in the `App keys` tab.

Answer (score 0):

> Navigate to your function in the Azure portal and click on Manage and
>   find the Host Keys section. Click on the Copy button in the _master
>   row to copy the master key to your clipboard.

**Source:** [Get the function's master key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http#get-the-functions-master-key)

If you need to retrieve the master key inside an ARM template, take a look at the **[listkeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#list)** function.

Comment: sorry, my mistake with my question I want to use PowerShell to get a master key, In Azure Function 1x with syntax
$masterKey = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://mydomain.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions/admin/masterkey -Headers @{"Authorization"=$accessToken;"If-Match"="*"} ).Masterkey.
And I detect 'https://mydomain.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions/admin/masterkey' is not work in 2x so, I want no find some 'scm api' to instead It